# Simple search results web part only displaying for myself and not other users

Tags: search-results, people-search

I use Sharepoint Online with O365 licenses.
I created a test employee directory page that's based on people search results web part + a custom display template from [Create a Simple SharePoint 2013 Employee Directory on Office365](http://sympmarc.com/2015/01/08/create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-employee-directory-on-office365-part-3-create-display-templates/). I can do some coding, but I'm not a developer nor a Sharepoint developer, so I'm a little bit stuck.

My problem is: currently the page is working, but **only I am able to see the search results part of the page, other users just get a blank**. They somehow do get the top *alphabetic sort buttons*, and *they also get the refiners on the left pane*, but somehow just the middle section where search bar and results who are BLANK.

The users I tested with all are admin (IT users), I made sure that they have access to the site, page, had the page published, checked in, everything.

I don't know why some parts of the page like the refiners on the left show, but not the center part, which is the whole thing, would show blank. I think if it was a permission issue, they'd get an error outright, instead of getting the side refiners but not the search results web part.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

The 2 new display templates I was using needed to be checked in/published/and approved before being accessible to all users.
I did it and now it displays just fine for users other than myself.